# Indoctrination vs brainwashing

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the defining difference between indoctrination and brainwashing? From my own understanding, I believe the definition of both to be (I’ll use religion for my example):
Indoctrination: teaching a person about a religion, like always taking them to church from a young age, but allowing them to choose whether they want to believe and live by that religion. 
Brainwashing: To force a person into believing a religion by means of well, force, etc.
I am not sure if this is correct or not. I see people look at indoctrination as a bad thing but from the definition I gave, I wouldn’t say that it is a bad thing. And that is what leads me to ask my question.

Comment: Do dictionaries agree with your own understandings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion may come from the historical existence of ‘indoctrination camps’, usually run by Communist regimes, which exacted a form of obedience through hardship, forced education, deprivation, humiliation, and sometimes torture. Non-aggressive indoctrination is as you describe: in a religious setting, the willing reception towards, and acceptance of, doctrine.

Brainwashing, on the other hand, is a more forceful and invasive process on an unwilling or unwitting subject, which involves coercion, torture, drugs, hypnotic suggestion and other methods to affect behavior. Theoretically, brainwashing leaves the subject thus affected not consciously aware of the brainwashing experience, and unaware of the altered motivations behind their actions.

The protagonist of the ‘Jason Bourne’ action movies and novels is an example of brainwashing taken to an extreme I don’t believe exists in the real world.

Comment: Your answer would benefit greatly with some citations, sources, and examples... unless you are an expert in such coercive techniques.

Answer (score 1):

According to online dictionary definitions [indoctrinate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/indoctrinate) and [brainwash](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainwashing) are near synonyms, however *indoctrinate* is a much older (17th century) word which originally merely meant "teach", although it seems to have been applied mainly to the teaching of religion: *brainwashing* as a word did not appear until the 1950s.

The difference between the two words is that *brainwashing* originally described coercive techniques applied to unwilling subjects (there were suggestions that [Gary Powers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Gary_Powers) had been brainwashed after his U2 plane was brought down over the USSR in 1960 and spy fiction and movies like [The Ipcress File](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_IPCRESS_File) included supposed brainwashing sequences) whereas *indoctrination* has usually been thought of as a gentler and longer-term process applied to children and willing converts. The definition of *brainwashing* in popular usage has, however been broadened to include what would previously have been thought of as *indoctrination* ("The government brainwashed us into supporting the war", "North Koreans are all brainwashed", "ISIS fighters are brainwashed into carrying out suicide attacks" and so on).

The negative implications of *indoctrination* come from the fact that much indoctrination involves presenting the subject only with material and sources which support the views held by the person or organisation doing the indoctrinating, and classifying other material and sources as evil or incompatible with the views being promoted (the attitude of some fundamentalist Christian organisations to The Origin of Species being an example)